# Jenkins, specifying JAVA_HOME

Tags: java, ubuntu, jenkins, java-home

I installed openjdk-6-jdk on my ubuntu box using apt-get.

In system info jenkins is telling me Java.Home is `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/jre`

However when I specify that directory as `JAVA_HOME` in Jenkins : "configure system", it returns error message saying that directory does not look like a jdk directory.

it is also failing to pick up my maven install.

Am I missing something obvious ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your JAVA_HOME variable must be set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk and it must be available  for the user that starts Jenkins.

***From Kyle Strand comment:***

*As of April 2015 (I think), Jenkins requires Java7. Also note that the java binary path (JAVA) must be set to the correct version if the system default is still Java 6. Finally, for anyone wondering where these variables are set, it's in a config file listed with the installation instructions on the Jenkins webpage (e.g. for Debian it's /etc/default/jenkins).*

Comment: As of April 2015 (I think), Jenkins requires Java7. Also note that the java binary path (`JAVA`) must be set to the correct version if the system default is still Java 6. Finally, for anyone wondering where these variables are set, it's in a config file listed with the installation instructions on the Jenkins webpage (e.g. for Debian it's `/etc/default/jenkins`).

Answer (score 9):

Using Jenkins 2 (2.3.2 in my case), the right way seems to insert the following into your pipeline file:

```
env.JAVA_HOME="${tool 'jdk1.8.0_111'}"
env.PATH="${env.JAVA_HOME}/bin:${env.PATH}"
```

"jdk1.8.0_111" beeing the name of the java configuration initially registered into Jenkins

Comment: This is in line with the Cloudbees recommendation as well: https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/204421664-Select-which-Java-JDK-to-use-in-Pipeline

Comment: Is there anyway to retrieve the java home from the tool using it's name outside of pipelines as well? E.g. in a freestyle job.

Answer (score 6):

On CentOS 6.x and Redhat 6.x systems, the openjdk-devel package contains the jdk.  It's sensible enough if you are familiar with the -devel pattern used in RedHat, but confusing if you're looking for a jdk package that conforms to java naming standards.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing the same issue and for me downgrading the `JAVA_HOME` from *jdk12* was not the plausible option like said in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8185849/7973229). So I did a trial and error experiment and I got the Jenkins running without even downgrading the version of `JAVA_HOME`.

#### Steps:

- open configuration `$ sudo vi /etc/init.d/jenkins`
- Comment following line:

```
 #JAVA=`type -p java`
```

- Introduced the line mentioned below. (Note: Insert the specific path of JDK in your machine.)

```
 JAVA=`type -p /usr/lib/jdk8/bin/java`
```

- Reload systemd manager configuration: `$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload`
- Start Jenkins service: `$ sudo systemctl start jenkins`

  ```
  ● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2020-05-31 21:05:30 CEST; 9min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Process: 9055 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/jenkins start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  ```

Answer (score 5):

I just wanted to add a solution for Windows machines.

- Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard, SP1
- Jenkins 2.89.4
- Java version 8.171

Symptom: Jenkins service starts and immediately stops.
`Jenkins.wrapper.log` has a line indicating the incorrect path to Java:

> - Starting C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_141\bin\java -Xrs -Xmx6g -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\war"

The fix: Jenkins has the path hard-coded in `jenkins.xml`. Change the path to the new Java location.

```
<env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%BASE%"/>
<!--
if you'd like to run Jenkins with a specific version of Java, specify a full path to java.exe.
The following value assumes that you have java in your PATH.
-->
<executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\bin\java</executable>
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
```

You can also use Windows Environment Variables, but I wasn't successful with that and I don't think the Java installer updates those, so you'd need to update that by hand every time anyway.

```
<env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%BASE%"/>
<!--
if you'd like to run Jenkins with a specific version of Java, specify a full path to java.exe.
The following value assumes that you have java in your PATH.
-->
<executable>%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java</executable>
<arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "%BASE%\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8080 --webroot="%BASE%\war"</arguments>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is an old thread but for more recent Jenkins versions (in my case Jenkins 2.135) that require a particular java JDK the following should help:

Note: This is for Centos 7 , other distros may have differing directory locations although I believe they are correct for ubuntu also.

Modify `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` and set variable `JENKINS_JAVA_CMD="/<your desired jvm>/bin/java"` (root access require)

Example:

```
JENKINS_JAVA_CMD="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk/bin/java"
```

Restart Jenkins (if jenkins is run as a service `sudo service jenkins stop` then `sudo service jenkins start`)

The above fixed my Jenkins install not starting after I upgraded to Java 10 and Jenkins to 2.135

[java](/questions/tagged/java) [jenkins](/questions/tagged/jenkins) [java-home](/questions/tagged/java-home) [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu) [centos](/questions/tagged/centos)

Answer (score 3):

`openjdk-6` is a Java runtime, not a JDK (development kit which contains `javac`, for example). Install `openjdk-6-jdk`.

Maven also needs the JDK.

**[EDIT]** When the JDK is installed, use `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk` for `JAVA_HOME` (i.e. without the `jre` part).

Comment: that was a typo in the question, I installed the full jdk (javac works). Also mvn works outside of jenkins.

Comment: At first I thought "oh, c'mon, there is a needed jdk folder there", but a suggested installation probably helped as I didn't have all the needed jdk stuff.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you coming to this issue and have access to configure your Jenkins Agents, you can set the `JAVA_HOME` from the Jenkins > Nodes > "the agent name" > Configure page:

[Setting "per agent" environment variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZyR8.png)

Comment: I am facing the same issue related to JAVA_HOME. it gives me error like "'java' is not executable on Java_Home or Path". How can we set the environment variable of Java_home from docker file on Jenkins?

Answer (score 1):

In Jenkins try setting `JAVA_HOME` to `/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk`

Comment: hmmm ... what do you mean by "in jenkins?".

Comment: @jayunit100 I think he meant in jenkins config (/jenkins/configure), but it didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone has similar problems, I used the default sudo apt-get installs for the relevant packages and here are the correct settings:

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386
```

and

```
MAVEN_HOME=/usr/share/maven2
```

Answer (score 1):

After half of the day trying different solutions for running correct JDK version to start Jenkins service, following helped in my case on Ubuntu 20.04.

sudo gedit jenkins.service in /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants

Uncomment JAVA_HOME variable in jenkins.service file and set to your JDK directory (in my case **/usr/local/bin/jdk-17.0.7**)

Environment="JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/bin/jdk-17.0.7"

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading from Ubuntu 10.0.4 to 12.0.4 we got wrong footed. 
We had a JDK installation configured (auto-configured?) pointing to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
this no longer contained a JDK, 
Changing to /usr/lib/jvm/default-java fixed, and should make for a seamless java-7 upgrade.

So in answer to the question: do not specify JAVA_HOME on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 12.04 I had to install 
**openjdk-7-jdk**

then **javac** was working !

then I could use

`/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64`

as path and jenkins didn't complain anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Download package rpm package from http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/  you can give additional java location like I have default 1.7 java in my system but I am using /opt/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java for jenkins. Open jenkins startup script /etc/init.d/jenkins and add additional java here, I m case I have added /opt/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java,

Search usable Java as /usr/bin/java might not point to minimal version required by Jenkins.

See http://www.nabble.com/guinea-pigs-wanted-----Hudson-RPM-for-RedHat-Linux-td25673707.html

candidates="
/opt/jdk1.8.0_60/bin/java

Answer (score -2):

i saw into 
Eclipse > Preferences>installed JREs > JRE Definition
i found the directory of java_home
so it's 
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_17.jdk/Contents/Home