# JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly (only from jenkins)

Tags: java, ant, jenkins

Trying to setup jenkins but my builds fails with:

```
$ ant test
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
Build step 'Invoke Ant' marked build as failure
```

If I manually run "ant test" on the machine it works just fine and the JAVA_HOME is set to the exact same value. Any idea why it fails when jenkins try to run it ? Are there any more environment variabled involved ( I could not see any though ) ?

Comment: Are you sure that `JAVA_HOME` is set for the user running Jenkins?

Comment: @devnull Yes, as if I change it the "We cannot execute..." message update to the new value while still failing.

Comment: maybe you need JDK, not JRE?

Comment: @user1516873 Tried that too, but same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jenkins, specifying JAVA\_HOME](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185593/jenkins-specifying-java-home)

Comment: I think `JAVA_HOME` should be the `/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64` root directory. Ant seems to guess `JAVA_HOME` when it's incorrect or not set according to http://stackoverflow.com/a/1558792/637889 which might explain why Ant works and Jenkins does not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was this, I had forgot to check the box "Restrict where this project can be run" in the project configuration. Thus the testing tried to execute on "master" where JAVA_HOME was not the same as expected on the build executor I intended to run it on. Thus where I tested and where it actually ran was different machines.

Answer (score 11):

For others, I had to add the `PATH` `/usr/bin/` to my PATH variable within Jenkins. (Find your correct path using `which java`).

Jenkins > `Manage Jenkins` > `Configure System`

Add an `Environment Variable` >>

`e.g:`

Name: `PATH`
Value: `/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin/`

### Screenshot

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Set `JAVA_HOME` in your Jenkins system config in Jenkins 2.107.1.

open your jenkins, e.g. http://192.168.1.12:9090, then add `/configure` to the url, 
that is `http://192.168.1.12:9090/configure`, then you can find like next:

[image]

Comment: It would be grateful/helpful if provide some more info about the steps.

Answer (score 1):

For me the options above did not help, solved by creating a link to what's asked:

```
sudo ln -s ${actual_java_location} /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
```

actual_java_location can be read by this:

```
 readlink -f $(which java)
```