# how to run openlaszlo 4.9.0 in ubuntu12.04?

Tags: red5, ubuntu-12.10, openlaszlo, java-home

I am Using Ubuntu 12.04 and i want to run OpenLaszlo 4.9.0 in my system. I have read many tutorial, e.g.

> http://wiki.openlaszlo.org/Installing_OpenLaszlo#Installing_the_DevKit_on_Unix.2FLinux

that say that put server in JAVA_HOME but i do not know where is JAVA_HOME in Ubuntu 12.04.

I have OpenLaszlo also . But I do not know how to start server of OpenLaszlo and where to put it? or how many things required for it? please tell me. I have Red5 server,i have install java-7-openjdk.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Setting JAVA_HOME in Ubuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/277806/how-to-set-java-home

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_HOME is an environment variable. It stores the path to java runtime environment (jre). You can have several JVMs installed on your system, of course. So JAVA_HOME defines the default one.
Setting this variable after installing Ubuntu package from the repository is a little tricky. It is discussed, for example, here:

[Jenkins, specifying JAVA_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185593/jenkins-specifying-java-home),

[What is the correct target for the JAVA_HOME envrionment variable for a Linux OpenJDK Debian-based distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/663658/what-is-the-correct-target-for-the-java-home-envrionment-variable-for-a-linux-op)

OpenLaszlo is a Web-application that should be run under some application server (usually Apache TomCat or its derivatives such as IBM WebSphere Application Server Community Edition).

It is available on the off.site as a bundle that includes TomCat and also as a .war file (a servlet) that should be deployed under your application server.

In the 1st case you can extract an archive wherever you want (read carefully about file permissions). But at the moment the server starts it needs Java system files so JAVA_HOME should be already defined.