# Unable to provide JAVA_HOME path in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

I have setup Jenkins in a linux environment . Installed the JAVA by running

> yum install java -y

Now I am unable to find the path of JDK which has to be provided as JAVA_HOME . Whatever path I give ends up in an error.

Inside /usr/lib/jvm I see these files and folders and none is taken by Jenkins

1. java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.amzn2.x86_64
2. jre
3. jre-1.8.0
4. jre-1.8.0-openjdk
5. jre-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.171-8.b10.amzn2.x86_64
6. jre-openjdk

Comment: It's very unclear. Is your jenkins server already works? are you trying to run a job which requires java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins, specifying JAVA\_HOME](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185593/jenkins-specifying-java-home)

Comment: do a `java --version`  you will get a version number and then do a `whereis java 1.8.0.1` or  `locate java 1.8.0.1`